# Determining probability after standardizing for given problem

Tags: statistics

During the log phase of bacterial growth the size of the colony grows exponentially. Let $R$ be the ratio of the biomass at time 1 hour to the initial biomass. Then $R=e^r$ where $r$ is the instantaneous growth rate. Assume that this ratio has mean $\mu_R=1.3$ and standard deviation $\sigma_R=.2$. Compute $P\{ \bar{R}>1.55\}$.

Can someone help me understand if part (b) is correct or not?

(b)$P\{\bar{R}>1.55\}=P\{\frac{\bar{R}-1.3}{(.2/5)}>\frac{1.55-1.3}{(.2/5)}\}=2.06 \times 10^{-10}$ (This does not seem right)

It does not seem right to me, but I cannot think of any other way to do it.

Here $\mu_{\bar{R}}=1.3$ and $\sigma_{\bar{R}}=.2/5$.

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of text and equations.  Instead, typeset in full using *MathJax*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I will be sure to do that next time. Do you see an error in my answer to this problem?

Comment: Do it *THIS TIME*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Hi David, I wrote it out. Can you address my question now?

Comment: Your calculation looks fine to me. A sample size of $25$ isn't really large enough to assume the sampling distribution of $\bar{R}$ is normal unless you have some prior information about the shape of the distribution of the population from which you're sampling. But, if you're safe to assume $\bar{R}$ is normal, you're okay.

Comment: What are the units on $\mu_R$ and $\sigma_R$?